# Topology, boundary & Interior

Tags: general-topology

I got these assignments on interior and boundary (Topology), which I've solved but I'm not sure if my solutions are correct so I thought I can ask for advice here.

I got 3 sets:

$D_1=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|<5, 4x+3y=7\}$

$D_2=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|>6\}$

$D_3=\{(x,y):4x+3y=7\}$

I've drawn them as can be seen below, I'll upload links to the pictures since I can not post pictures here yet.

Here is $D_1$:

[image]

Here is $D_2$:

[image]

$D_3$ is the same as $D_1$ but without the blue space.

Now the next step is for me to decide and mark the Interior points and the boundary points of each Graph, and to also decide which of the sets are open, which are closed, and which are neither.

After working on them I came to this conclusion:

$D_1$: Does not have an interior, and the boundary is the equation line ($4x+3y=7$), inside (the part that is inside $|x|+|y|<5$) the blue area. And that $D_1$ is an open set.

$D_2$: Does not have an interior, or any boundaries, and is also an open set.

$D_3$:Does not have an interior, but again the boundaries are the question line ($4x+3y=7$) and is neither an open or a closed set.

Can anyone please check these solutions and tell me if they're correct, and if not, help me correct them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You claim that D1 and D2 have no interior but that they are open. This does not add up, for the interior of any set is the largest open subset contained in the given set. Maybe you should give us the definitions and arguments you used to come to your conclusions so that we can tell you where your mistake come from.

Comment: To be honest now when I think of it I'm not sure how I came to these conclusions. But I'm starting to realize myself also that I'm wrong. Could you describe to me how I should think to arrive at the correct conclusions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation for $D1$ means a conjunction of both requirements, so the $D1$ set is an intersection of a square and a line. As a result $D1$ is a line segment. I leave it to you to determine if the segment contains its endpoints or not.

**Edit:** after the OP's comment, correct, the$D1$  segment doesn't contain its endpoints, because the square is open (interior without the border).

And the segment has boundary points only and no interior.  (Of course, that holds when considered in a plane! A segment as a subset of a 1-dimensional space of its line *does have* an interior, and it is open there.)

On the other hand $D2$ has interior only and no boundary points.

And $D3$ has boundary points only, just like $D1$.

Comment: I don't think it has an endpoint, does it? Since it can never be =5 but approaches very very close to 5.

But also, what does that tell us about the interior and boundaries? 

Topology is not my strongest side.

Comment: @Eulersfunction Correct, see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it also tells us to mark the interior, everything within the square is counted as the interior, or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @Eulersfunction Nope, points inside the square make an interior of the square, but your set is **not** a square. The set D1 consists of point that belong to the square **and** to the line, that is points of a line segment. How do you want the whole square to be an interior of a segment? Check again: D1 is an [*intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the square and the line.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand now. So in D1, the line part that is inside the square is the boundary points? And what is D2's interior, just the area inside of the square (even though the square is >6 and not <6?) 
And D2 is an open set just like D1 right? 

And D3 is neither an open or a closed set if I now have understood it right? 
Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @Eulersfunction D2 interior is the coloured area – everything outside the square. And it is an open set, it does not contain its boundary points.